# Testing multiple methods calling order

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, xctest

I have 3 methods that are related to a specific class which is defined as follows:

```
class MyClass: NSObject {
    func myMethod() {
        methodA()
        methodB()
        methodC()
    }
    func methodA() {}
    func methodB() {}
    func methodC() {}
}
```

I need to test that `myMethod` has called all 3 methods by the order they are implemented: `methodA` then `methodB` then `methodC`
 to be tested with XCode Unit Tests, regardless of the implementation of these methods, I have created a subclass in the test case that looks like the following:

```
class ChildClass: MyClass {
    var method1CallingDate: Date?
    var method2CallingDate: Date?
    var method3CallingDate: Date?

    override func methodA() {
        super.methodA()
        method1CallingDate = Date()
    }
    override func methodB() {
        super.methodB()
        method2CallingDate = Date()
    }
    override func methodC() {
        super.methodC()
        method3CallingDate = Date()
    }
}
```

Now in the test method, I start by calling those 3 methods, then I assert that all three dates are not nil first, then compare them like this:

```
XCTAssertLessThan(method1CallingDate, method2CallingDate)
XCTAssertLessThan(method2CallingDate, method3CallingDate)
```

The problem I ran into was that the test sometimes succeeds and sometimes fails, i guess due to `Date` object is (randomly) the same between 2 of the method calls.
Is there a better way to test the order of calling multiple methods ?

**p.s.** this is easily done in the Android SDK `org.mockito.Mockito.inOrder`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make a mock object that records the order. No dates, no strings. Just an enumeration.

```
class MockMyClass: MyClass {
    enum invocation {
        case methodA
        case methodB
        case methodC
    }
    private var invocations: [invocation] = []

    override func methodA() {
        invocations.append(.methodA)
    }

    override func methodB() {
        invocations.append(.methodB)
    }

    override func methodC() {
        invocations.append(.methodC)
    }

    func verify(expectedInvocations: [invocation], file: StaticString = #file, line: UInt = #line) {
        if invocations != expectedInvocations {
            XCTFail("Expected \(expectedInvocations), but got \(invocations)", file: file, line: line)
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the test:

```
mock.verify(expectedInvocations: [.methodA, .methodB, .methodC])
```

No async waiting. Simple to call. Clear failure messages.

Comment: clean answer, thank you. by the way, what are those file & line params do ? I couldn't find an explanation in Apple Docs for them.

Comment: The parameters with those default arguments capture the file name and line number >at the call site<. So if there's a failure, XCTFail will point to the call to `mock.verify`, not to the `XCTFail` line. …I'm currently working on a book on iOS unit testing, so this will be in there.

Comment: what's the name of your book and when will it be published ?

Comment: _iOS Unit Testing by Example: XCTest Tips and Techniques Using Swift_ https://pragprog.com/book/jrlegios/ios-unit-testing-by-example

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this using a `String` to keep track of the order:

```
class ChildClass: MyClass {
    var order = ""

    override func methodA() {
        super.methodA()
        order = String((order + "A").suffix(3))
    }
    override func methodB() {
        super.methodB()
        order = String((order + "B").suffix(3))
    }
    override func methodC() {
        super.methodC()
        order = String((order + "C").suffix(3))
    }
}
```

Then, just check that `order` is `"ABC"`.

---

Or, if it is valid to call `B` multiple times between `A` and `C`:

```
class ChildClass: MyClass {
    var order = ""

    override func methodA() {
        super.methodA()
        order = order.replacingOccurrences(of: "A", with: "") + "A"
    }
    override func methodB() {
        super.methodB()
        order = order.replacingOccurrences(of: "B", with: "") + "B"
    }
    override func methodC() {
        super.methodC()
        order = order.replacingOccurrences(of: "C", with: "") + "C"
    }
}
```

**Example:**

```
let c = ChildClass()
c.methodA()
c.methodB()
c.methodB()
c.methodC()

print(c.order)
```

> ```
> ABC
> ```

Comment: using "ABC" to check the order of calling resembles my usage for those 3 dates variables in the question. but what's the benefit of using .suffix(3) ?

Comment: `suffix(3)` keeps just the last 3 calls in case they’re called multiple times.

Comment: The second answer better matches your use of dates, because it only tracks the most recent calls of the methods.

Answer (score 1):

I've become a fan of using `XCTestExpectation` for this kind of thing. Here's an option.

```swift
class MyTestableClass: MyClass {
    var methodAHandler: (() -> Void)?
    // ...

    override func methodA() {
        methodAHandler?()  
        super.methodA()
    }
```

And then in your test case

```swift
   let expA = XCTestExpectation(description: "Method A Called")
   let expB = ...
   let expo = ...

   objectUnderTest.methodAHandler = { expA.fulfill() }
   /// ...

   objectUnderTest.myMethod()

   // ensure you use the enforceOrder param, which is optional
   wait(for: [expA, expB, expC], timeout: 1.0, enforceOrder: true)
```

`XCTestExpectation` is made more for async testing, so the wait is slightly funny. But, it does do what you need, and would keep working even if eventually the internals of `myMethod` become asynchronous for some reason.

While I haven't used it myself, you also might want to check out [Cuckoo](https://github.com/Brightify/Cuckoo). It's a mocking framework for Swift.

Comment: awesome solution. for the Cuckoo tool I'm not a fan for such tools because every tool like so has its own different syntax or what's called (Domain Specific Language) which you eventually end up stuck with their own language and method of implementation which may break with an XCode upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

You're not asking the right question here. From a unit testing point of view you should not know/care that the tested method calls other methods, or even if other methods exist.

Unit tests should validate some observable result of the tested method. Anything that happens inside the tested method is irrelevant in the context of a unit test.

That's because unit tests should validate that the unit behaves as expected, i.e. they should validate against the specifications, not against the implementation.

Let's consider a simple example, unit testing a `isPrime(n)` function. Unless you're doing performance testing, you only care if the function returns the appropriate result for a couple of numbers. You don't care if the function checks all possible divisors, or if it uses a database of all known prime numbers, or if delegates the prime check to some 3rd party library/service.

The situation is not much different from yours. The fact that the three methods are called in a certain order needs to be validate via the external interface of the tested unit. For example if the three methods make API calls, then mock the API client and expect it to be requested three times, and with the expected URL/payload. If calling the three methods don't result in any noticeable changes, then there's not much you can test from the start, so again the fact that three methods are called in a certain order become irrelevant.

Unit testing is about validating the result of the execution of that unit, not anything more. Now, in an imperative programming language, the input->output functions are a minority, however this doesn't mean that we can't indirectly test if the function behaves as expected. You can use mocks, or validate some properties of the object after the function executes. Again, if there are no ways of externally checking the order of methods, then you have no specs to validate against.

Comment: You may need to verify the order for some design requirements like the one I faced in my project, and as you mentioned I shouldn't not go for the extra step to verify the order every time i test a method that calls other methods, it all depends on the requirements.

Comment: @JAHelia I've rephrased the answer to include more details, hope this answer better your question. Note that specifications usually don't involve implementation details, like which methods to call, thus unit tests should not care about that.